# Location and Directory cause 500 error

Tags: apache, .htaccess, directory

I have an .htacces file and I am trying to open up access to a file and folder within a protected folder.

The file is index.php so I do the following:

```
<Files index.php>
    Order Allow,Deny
    Allow from All
    Satisfy Any
</Files>
```

This works and give me access to this file. This file requires assets from the `assets/` directory. So I try to open that directory up by doing the following:

```
<Directory "/assets">
    Order Allow,Deny
    Allow from All
    Satisfy Any
</Directory>
```

But this is giving me a 500 error. Not sure why.

Comment: I bet /assets doesn't exist, as /assets is not really in hte root directory of the server but rather inside your document root or inside the directory the .htaccess file is. Whichever is true, either use the full absolute path, or a relative one.

Comment: so assuming I changed it to "./assets", then that would mean if assets is at the same directory level as .htacces then apache would be able to resolve to the directory ok?

Comment: either `./assets` or simply `assets` should do, yes. To go a level up, use `..`, as always.

Comment: If it doesn'T work, use the absolute path. I'm not sure if Directoy containers do work on realtive paths, and I cannot test right now either. The documentation isn'T really clear on this.

Comment: tried absolute. not sure why that doesn't work either.

Comment: I don'T see a reason for it not to work atm either. But as an alternative, have you tried placing a `.htaccess` file into the assets-directory, withput any container? that should work, too...

Comment: no. that is my next step.

Comment: I couldn't get the Directory directive working but placing .htaccess inside of the assets folder worked out. thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use the `<Directory>` container inside an htaccess file (which is essentially like the `<Directory>` container itself). If you want to allow access to assets, then create an htaccess file inassets with just:

```
Order Allow,Deny
Allow from All
```

Comment: OK I had a hunch this was the case. Anyways I ended up doing exactly as you said and that solved my issue. On a side note, you can't use <Location> in an htaccess file either correct?

Comment: @moesef [No, you can't](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#location). The context that you can use location is only in server or vhost config.